# Can I use pd.cut with reg.expressions to divide up the cabin values (Titanic Dataset)?

Tags: regex, pandas, seaborn

Here is what a sample from the dataset Cabin_hunt looks like:

```
     Fare      Cabin  Pclass   Ticket  \
583  40.1250   A10       1     13049   
208  27.7208   A11       1  PC 17613   
475  52.0000   A14       1    110465   
556  39.6000   A16       1     11755   
331  29.7000   A18       1  PC 17580   
284  26.0000   A19       1    113056   
599  56.9292   A20       1  PC 17485   
737  512.3292  B101      1  PC 17755   
815   0.0000   B102      1    112058   
215  42.5000   B11       1    113038   
329  57.9792   B18       1    111361   
523  57.9792   B18       1    111361   
269  135.6333  C99       1  PC 17760   
97   63.3583   D10 D12   1  PC 17759   
350  63.3583   D10 D12   3  PC 17759   
765  77.9583   D11       3     13502
```

I want to divide up the cabins into groups by the starting letter, but I don't want to drop the numbers following them as I may want to further divide each group based on their respective numbers.

After creating the groups  I plan to graph each group separated by Pclasses to see any correlation between Cabin letter and Pclass.

I was thinking of using pd.cut but it seems I would have to use regular expressions? 
    d =pd.cut(Cabin_hunt.Cabin,('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')

I was trying to use the brackets to indicate a set of characters as below:

```
'A[0-9][0-9]'
```

but I couldn't figure out how to activate the special usage of brackets.

Nonetheless, if I cut up 'Cabins' by letters using pd.cut, I will only have access to that column right? Not the whole dataframe it seems.  I want to be able to graph both the Cabin and PClass.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` with `Cabin_hunt.Cabin.str[0]`

```
Cabin_hunt.groupby([Cabin_hunt.Cabin.str[0], Cabin_hunt.Pclass]).size().unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. All I needed to add to Cabin was str[0] for groupby. 
You have been very helpful recently, and I've learned a lot from you. 
Thank you piRSQuared.